# Inverse Laplace Transform of Discontinuous Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm currently studying transform of discontinuous and periodic functions (Differential Equations.) I was presented with the following question.

$$\dfrac{se^{-3s}}{s^2+4s+5}$$

(Sorry, I couldn't get the formatting to work properly. Feel free to fix it. )

I've identified $F(s)$ as:

$$\dfrac{s}{s^2+4s+5}$$

but I'm a little stuck on how to find the inverse Laplace transform of this. Do I complete the square? I'd appreciate some advice here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the square is a great way to go.  We could say
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{s}{s^2+4s+5} &=
\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+1} \\ &=
\frac{(s+2)-2}{(s+2)^2+1} \\ &=
\frac{(s+2)}{(s+2)^2+1} - \frac{2}{(s+2)^2+1}
\end{align}
$$
Where could you go from there?

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that? Well it's certainly been a long day. Thanks!

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Ha dude I happened to learn this week in my ODE class! You complete the square first $\frac{s}{s^2+4s+5}=\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+1}$, then split this thing into cosine and sine's Laplace transforms: $\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+1} = \frac{s+2}{(s+2)^2+1} - \frac{2}{(s+2)^2+1} $.

Comment: haha nice! Appreciate your time. :)